# My nokia lumia 635 wont detect my ear buds

Tags: lumia

I am using a pair of skull candy earbuds and the phone dosent register that there are ear buds plugged in. But the weird thing is that i plugged in a pair of my friends earbuds and they worked. and then i plugged my earbuds into his phone and the ear buds worked. what could i do to make them work on my phone. Oh and i have restarted my phone and turned it on and off again.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is a mismatch between size of jack... Sometimes it just gives the music... No audio... I am sure u would have tried rotating the hands-free.. If you haven't then try it.